# Lua - Detect if string contains valid characters for a password

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, preg-match, coronasdk

I use the following code in PHP to validate if a password includes invalid characters

```
function validate_password($str) {
    if(strlen($str) < 5 || strlen($str) > 30) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return preg_match('/^[-._A-Za-z0-9]*$/',$str);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the same in Lua but not sure the best way to check if a string contains only certain characters.   My valid characters are alphanumeric with the addition of "-" and "."

```
local function validate_password(str)
    if string.len(str) < 5 or string.len(str) > 30 then
        return false
    else
        if(str:match("%W")) then
                -- this isn't right. need to check if alpha numeric or - or .
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You shouldn't even be able to validate a password: Hash it and store the hash.

Comment: @daurnimator - I use this function to validate the password before I hash and store it. Maybe it's not necessary, but I validate the password whenever somebody enters a password on my site ( register or login ).  If the password is not valid, I don't bother to connect to the db at all.

Comment: you shouldn't be limiting character set or length though. Best practice for password choice is automatic generation. As you only store the hash, the length does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return #str >= 5 and #str <= 30 and str:find('^[%-%.%w_]+$') ~= nil`

Note 1: as mentioned in the comments, `~= nil` part can be removed as the position returned by `find` will be evaluated as `true` (when it's not nil) in logical operators. However, since it's a number, it will fail when used in `validate_password(str) == true` comparisons (since `1 == true` is not `true`). An alternative is to use `not str:find('[^...]')` as suggested by Egor.

Note 2: as mentioned in the comments, `-` and `.` don't need to be escaped in this particular case. However, since `-` is a range operator inside square brackets `[_-.]` is *not* the same as `[-._]`, as it will match nothing as the range of symbols between `_` and `.` is empty. It's safe to escape `-` and `.` even inside square brackets.

Comment: Underscore is not part of `%w` pattern.  `and not str:find'[^-._%w]'`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, correct; updated; thanks. `not str:find'[^...]'` is like a double negative ;).

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned `_` though! :) Also, `~= nil` clause can be removed.

Comment: Double negative is useful to get pure `true/false` value without comparison with `nil`. `not not` is kinda Lua idiom ;-)

Comment: @hjpotter92, technically, `~= nil` can be removed, but then the function will return `false` or a number, which will evaluate to `true`, but this may be unexpected in some cases (for example, `validate_password(...) == true` will fail when `find()` returns a number).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, agree; it's also a tad shorter ;); although one would need to know what [^...] means...

Comment: Is this your final answer?  I removed the "_"   return #str >= 5 and #str <= 30 and str:find('^[%-%.%w]+$') ~= nil

Comment: @fun_programming `str:find('^[-.%w]+$')` will also work. Not necessary to escape inside square braces.

Comment: @fun_programming, your original PHP solution includes '_'; not sure why you removed it as it's not included in %w pattern in Lua.

Comment: @hjpotter92, correct, no need to escape '-' in *this* case, but it's a range operator in square brackets, so one can be easily burned in an example like this `("._"):find('[_-.]+')` wondering why nothing gets matched. If it's part of a more complex expression, it can lead to a very subtle errors.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko - you are right that I removed '_' unnecessarily.